# C++ permutations of specified parts in 2D array

Tags: c++, graph-theory, permutation

I have a simple two 2D arrays (represented as [map](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/map/)), filled with 1 and 0.

```
    | A | B | C | D | sum
--------------------------
  A | 0 | 1 | 1 | 1 |  3
  B | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 |  1
  C | 1 | 0 | 0 | 1 |  2
  D | 1 | 0 | 1 | 0 |  1
```

it is representation of a [graph](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_theory), so the table is symmetrical to the main diagonal (no members has relation to themselves /no recursion/).
I need to generate permutations of specified columns/rows.
I know there's a [next_permutation()](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/next_permutation/) function, but i don't know how to use it (for 2D array representing graph), i guess i need to write own algorithm for just returning index of 2 columns/rows for switching. I cannot realize, that i would rewrite the whole table just because of switching 2 cols/rows.

And the most hard of all is, that switching all rows/cols is not neccessary, when there are rows, which has unique sum - this cols/rows (in my case A) can stay on their place, because it's clear to which member in second table they belong (= there's no more members with the same number of relations).

After i'll be able to generate permutations of A-D (its table), i can compare the generated table to the second and check, whether are same (that's what i have already done).

How can i do the permutations?

Comment: Maybe you should just explain what you want to get, do you want to list all possible graphs on 4 vertices?

Comment: i need to generate table with switched B and D (both have one relation)

Comment: D has 2 relations your math does not work.

Comment: Could be overkill for what you're doing, but have you looked at Boost.Graph?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are just 64 variants of bidirectional graphs like you describe with 4 vertices. In other words your graph contains 6 bits of information and is therefore easy to construct from numbers 0 to 63.